# Spacy Matcher date pattern will match hyphens, but not forward slashes?

Tags: python, spacy

I cannot find any reason why `pattern_2` works in the code below, but `pattern_1` does not. Why would the matcher be able to find the date pattern with hyphens, and not the date pattern with forward slashes?

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens.doc import Doc
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)  
doc: Doc = nlp('4/15/2021 4-15-2021')

pattern_1 = [{'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'ORTH': '/'}, {'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'ORTH': '/'}, {'IS_DIGIT': True}]
pattern_2 = [{'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'ORTH': '-'}, {'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'ORTH': '-'}, {'IS_DIGIT': True}]

matcher.add('DATE_PATTERN_1', None, pattern_1)
matcher.add('DATE_PATTERN_2', None, pattern_2)
matches = matcher(doc)
print(f"matches = {matches}")

for match_id, start, end in matches:
    matched_span = doc[start:end]
    print(matched_span.text)
```

OUTPUT:

> matches = [(93485516188963487, 1, 6)]

> 4-15-2021

Comment: The first one is a single token, `[t for t in doc]` shows `[4/15/2021, 4, -, 15, -, 2021]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one, `4/15/2021`, is parsed as a single token:

```py
print([t for t in doc])
# => [4/15/2021, 4, -, 15, -, 2021]
```

You may use a regex based pattern to detect this kind of token:

```py
pattern_1 = [{'TEXT':{'REGEX':r'^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?$'}}]
```

Then, the outcome will look like

```py
print(f"matches = {matches}")
# => matches = [(2279607876847626059, 0, 1), (93485516188963487, 1, 6)]
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    matched_span = doc[start:end]
    print(matched_span.text)

# => 4/15/2021
#    4-15-2021
```

The regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `/` - a `/` char
- `\d{1,2}/\d{2}` - one or two digits, `/`, two digits
- `(?:\d{2})?` - an optional sequence of two digits
- `$` - end of the string (here, token).